# Error "Trying to get non-object property" after calling a livewire function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using livewire to call a function that turns the user's role into "writer", the function in the livewire class is as follows :

```
class User extends Component
{
    public $users;

    public function turnWriter($id){
        DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(['role' => 'writer']);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user');
    }
}
```

calling the function on the blade template on the button inside the if statement at the end:

```
    <thead class="border-b bg-laravel">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-black px-6 py-4">
          Username
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-black px-6 py-4">
          Email
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-black px-6 py-4">
          Verified At
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-black px-6 py-4">
          Actions
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-sm font-medium text-black px-6 py-4">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead class="border-b">
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr class="bg-white border-b">
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                {{$user->name}}
            </td>
            <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                {{$user->email}}
            </td>
            @if(empty($user->email_verified_at))
            <td class="text-sm text-red-500 px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                Not Verified yet   
            @else
            <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
            {{$user->email_verified_at}}
            @endif
            </td>
            <td class="text-red-500 font-light px-6 py-4 hover:bg-red-400 hover:text-white">
                Block
            </td>
            @if($user->role == 'user')
            <td>
                <div>
                    <button wire:click="turnWriter({{ $user->id }})" class="text-white bg-teal-500 font-light px-6 py-4 hover:bg-teal-800">
                        Make Writer  
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>          
            @else
            <td class="text-white bg-emerald-600 font-light px-6 py-4 hover:bg-emerald-900">
                
                    Remove Writer role
                
            </td>
            @endif   
        </tr class="bg-white border-b">
        @endforeach                     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the controller function that returns the blade view:

```
    public function dashboard(){
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('role', 'user')->Orwhere('role', 'writer')->get();
        //dd($users);
        return view('users.dashboard',[
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
    }
```

The issue is, when clicking the button, the user's role does get changed to "writer" in the database, the problem comes afterwards, the view can't read the value or the property of $user for some reason and the following error pops up, the function however works just fine:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Livewire does not like `stdClass` variables. It only supports the types mentioned [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#important-notes). When you use a `DB::get()`, you get a collection of `stdClass`, and upon rehydrating the component (as what happens when you add a role to the user), it will convert all of the data to arrays. So, either always cast `toArray()` so you have an expected result set (and then don't use `->name`, but `['name']`), or use model collections.

I'd like to add that it's best practice to keep variables inside Livewire components, instead of having them in the main blade. If you don't need the `$users` variable in your `dashboard.blade`, then I highly suggest moving it to your component (in the `mount` method, for example)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used livewire but don't you think you should pass an argument to view? The $users variable is null in your case if you don't pass it.

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.user', [
        'users' => User::all(), //or User::where('role', 'writer')->get(); depending on your logic
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same issue, I am already passing the users parameter via the controller, and it's working (the page loads correctly for the first time), this error occurs only pressing the button that calls the livewire function

Comment: Maybe it's because you need to return users again after updating them. Obviously they are null

Comment: I tried this as well, didn't seem to work

Comment: Can you post the whole blade file, including js, too hard to help based on what you have provided

Comment: I edited the question to provide the whole blade file and the controller function that returns the view, I didn't use any js